# Java program, cycle works only 2 times

Tags: java

I'm making an exercise that asked me to make a program in java which does these things:

Suppose that you can buy from an automatic machine at school 1 piece of chocolate for 1$.
Inside the chocolate is a voucher. If you have 6 voucher you can get 1 piece of chocolate for free.
Suppose that you have N $ and you want to buy some chocolate. For example if you have 6$ you can get 7 piece of chocolate (because you have 6 voucher that are inside the 6 piece of chocolate and wit this 6 voucher you can get 1 piece of chocolate for free). Now you have only 1 voucher valid which is the voucher of the 7° piece of chocolate. For example with 12 $ you can get 14 piece of chocolate and remains to you 2 voucher.

Write a program which receives an N value and prints how many pieces of chocolate you can eat and how much valid voucher remains to you at the end. Use a cycle which change chocolate and voucher every time that
there are too much voucher for get 1 piece of chocolate for free.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ripasso {

public static void main (String [] args) {
    
        String risposta;
        int dollar,pieceOfChocolate,voucher,dollar2,voucher2,pieceOfChocolate2;
        Scanner tastiera = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How much dollar do you have");
        
        dollar = tastiera.nextInt();
        pieceOfChocolate = dollar;
        voucher = pieceOfChocolate;
       
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("You insert " + dollar + " dollar which gives you " + pieceOfChocolate + " piece of Chocolate");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("You also have " + voucher + " voucher");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Every time you have 6 valid voucher you can get 1 piece of chocolate for free");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("You can get " + (dollar/6) + " piece of Chocolate for free");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Now you have " + (pieceOfChocolate = (dollar/6) + pieceOfChocolate) +  " piece of Chocolate");
        System.out.println(""); 
        voucher = dollar%6;
        System.out.println("And you also have " + voucher + " voucher");
        
        boolean ciclo = true;
        
        while(ciclo){
            
            System.out.println("How much dollar do you have");
            
            dollar2 = tastiera.nextInt();
            voucher = dollar%6;
            voucher2 = dollar2%6;
            pieceOfChocolate = dollar2;
            pieceOfChocolate2 = (voucher2+voucher)/6;
            
            if (((voucher2+voucher)%6)<0){
                ciclo = false;
            } 
            
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("You can get " + (dollar2/6) + " piece of Chocolate for free");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Now you have " + (pieceOfChocolate = (dollar2/6) + pieceOfChocolate2 + pieceOfChocolate ) +  " piece of Chocolate");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("And also you have " + ((voucher2+voucher)%6) + " voucher");
            
            }

} 

}
```

If I want to insert for 3 time money, and calculate how many pieces of chocolate have and also valid voucher this program not work, only 2 time works. The third time shows the value of the 2 time.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Why do you do the modulus operation on vouchers? That does not seem useful at all.

Comment: Because of their similar spelling, I suspect that by "cicle" you mean "cycle". From there and context, I am inclined to think that the English word you actually want is "loop".

Comment: what i can do ?

Comment: I'm not talking about your variable naming, though we do prefer code written in English here.  Rather, I'm talking about the problem description.  That's rather more important from the perspective of answering the question.

Comment: i want a loop, every time people insert money the program print how much piece of chocolate he can get and also how much voucher get. If he has 6 voucher he can get 1 piece of chocolate for free. So for example first i time i have 6$ i get 7 piece of chocolate. Second time i have 8$ i get 8 piece of chocolate and remains to me 3 voucher. Third time i insert 13$ i get 14 piece of chocolate and exc ...

Comment: nobody can help me ?

Comment: Seriously?  No answer in 22 minutes and it's "nobody can help me?"

Comment: @JohnBollinger which answer ?

Comment: the first question which @NickHristov made i can't answer because i don't now the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this program meet your demand

```
int dollar,pieceOfChocolate,voucher,dollar2,voucher2,pieceOfChocolate2;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How much dollar do you have");

     dollar = in.nextInt();
    // voucher=
     pieceOfChocolate=dollar;
     voucher=pieceOfChocolate;
     pieceOfChocolate=dollar+voucher/6;
     voucher = voucher%6;
    System.out.println("you have  "+pieceOfChocolate+" chocolates and remaining voucher "+voucher);

    boolean ciclo = true;

    while(ciclo){

        System.out.println("How much dollar do you have");

        dollar2 = in.nextInt();
        pieceOfChocolate=dollar2;
     voucher = voucher+pieceOfChocolate;
     pieceOfChocolate=dollar2+voucher/6;
     voucher = voucher%6;

     if(voucher==0)
         break;

       System.out.println("you have  "+pieceOfChocolate+" chocolates and  remaining voucher "+voucher);
       }
```

Comment: Is this programs not working in your system?It theres any problem, let me know

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement is:

> Write a program wich receive an N value and print how much piece of
>   chocolate you can eat and how much valid voucher remains to you at the
>   end. Use a cicle wich change chocolate and voucher every time that
>   there are to much voucher for get 1 piece of chocolate for free. [sic]

The English translation is a bit tricky to follow, but what I think it asks for is rather different from what your code actually does.  Your program loops to perform multiple runs in which it requests an amount of money and attempts to directly compute the amount of chocolate and vouchers that can be obtained by spending all the money in the candy machine.

What the problem actually seems to be asking for, however, is a loop wherein at each iteration you reduce the number of vouchers by six if that many are available, otherwise you reduce the amount of money by one unit if any remains, else you quit the loop.  In each iteration you increase the number of chocolates purchased and the number of vouchers available by one each.  At the end, you then report the number of chocolates purchased and the number of vouchers left.  Doing that will not require any division or modular arithmetic.

---

Doing that is also inefficient, as you seem to recognize, but your approach to performing the computation more directly breaks down for large amounts of money.  If you really want to do it that way, contrary to the seeming intent of the assignment, then consider this approach:

- each dollar gets you one chocolate and one voucher
- each six vouchers gets you one chocolate and one voucher, for a *net* cost of five vouchers per chocolate
- but unless you started with 0 dollars, you must end with at least one voucher, because every purchase provides one.  (In other words, you cannot buy a chocolate with your last five vouchers.)

Thus, if you want to do it this way then the formulae would be

```
chocolate =
    dollars               // purchases for dollars
    + (dollars - 1) / 5;  // purchases for vouchers
```

and

```
vouchers = (dollars - 1) % 5 + 1;
```

Remember to account for the special case where you start with 0 dollars, and therefore end with 0 chocolate and 0 vouchers.